# How to find the Group with the Max value

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a database of students, I have to group them by their class and then find out which class has the most students. I know it's probably a stupid question but I can't come to the solution.

Sample data:

```
| Name | Class |
|------|-------|
|Tony| 4|
|Anna| 5|
|John| 4|
```

The output should show class number 4 has the most students

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  An appropriate database tag is also needed.

Comment: What if two classes have the same number of students?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row, then you can use:

```
select class, count(*)
from students
group by class
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This uses standard SQL functionality.  Your database may ahve some other method for choosing one row, such as `limit 1` or `select top (1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
select class ,COUNT(*) STUDENTCOUNT, dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) COUNTSL from Students
group by class
)
select NUMBER,STUDENTCOUNT FROM CTE WHERE COUNTSL=1
```

In above query I have used common table expression with window function dense_rank() and group by cluase.

With group by clause we first selected class with their student counts as studentcount.
dense_rank() is used to give an serial number to each row starting from one. To get the classes with highest student count I have used count(*)desc as order by clause form dense_rank(). It will generate same serial number for the classes with same number of students. So if highest number of student is 5 and there are two class having 5 number of students then both will be displayed.

Comment: Could you edit your post to have some explanation with it?

Comment: @NickN. Thanks a lot. While editing I have found a mistake in my query. I have replaced row_number() with dense_rank().